# i'm trying to change the format of excel data which i downloaded from google analytics, currently the data is in this format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| Country | date | users Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| India | Current date | 26195 |
| India | Previous date | 27820 |
| United kingdom | Current date | 15940 |
| United kingdom | Previous date | 10273 |
| Sweden | Current date | 11160 |
| Sweden | Previous date | 3804 |

i want to convert the data in below format

| Country | Previous date user count | Current date user count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| India | 27820 | 26195 |
| United Kingdom | 10273 | 15940 |
| Sweden | 3804 | 11160 |

After going through numerous videos on youtube and searches on google i couldn't find the answer, even chat gpt is not providing me how to do it, one of my colleague told me to do this manually, i have no one who could help me, there 227 countries in this list. please help

Comment: The thing is you don't know what to ask (no offense). This type of transformation is called **pivoting**. The other way around is called unpivoting. The major Excel tool for doing this is obviously using a Pivot Table. Then there is PowerQuery. Using any of them you can do it in a minute or so. it's easily doable in VBA. With the new Excel functions (Microsoft 365), it is also not that hard to do it using a single Excel formula. **Pivot** is the keyword. Here's a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvgXaKTHFHc) to a great Youtube video that covers it using an Excel formula.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be accomplished using `Power Query` with few clicks, and its a one time approach, next time when you add new data just refresh the imported table, done.

[image]

---

**Using Power Query :**

---

• Select some cell in your **Data Table**,

• **Data** Tab => **Get&Transform** => **From Table/Range**,

• When the **PQ Editor** opens: **Home** => **Advanced Editor**,

• Make note of all the 2 Tables Names,

• Paste the `M Code` below in place of what you see.

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="GAnalyticsData"]}[Content],
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Source, List.Distinct(Source[date]), "date", "users Count"),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Country", "Previous date", "Current date"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

---

• Change the Table name from **GAnalyticsData** to as **DataOutput** before importing it back into Excel, note that you need to select from **Home** tab --> **Close & Load** --> **Close & Load To** --> Select either **Existing Worksheet** or **New Worksheet** as per your preferences.

---

**Output:**

[image]

---

Using **MS365** Formulas one could try:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E15`

```
=LET(u,UNIQUE(GAnalyticsData[Country]),
ud,TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(GAnalyticsData[date]),1,-1)),
c,COLUMNS(ud),
HSTACK(VSTACK("Country",u),
VSTACK(ud,SORTBY(WRAPROWS(GAnalyticsData[users Count],c),ud))))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with `=UNIQUE(countries)` ,which will return your first column.

Then, try `=XLOOKUP(UNIQUE(countries), FILTER(countries, dates="Previous date"), FILTER(users_counts, dates="Previous date"))` for the second column. The third column would be the same, but with "Current date" instead of "Previous date".

Let me know if you need any further advice; the formulae may not work if you're using an older version of Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a Pivot Table:

[image]

Tkae field `Country` into rows section, field `date` into Columns section and field `users Count` into Values section.

It's just some clicks.

> [Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet
> data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

Answer (score 1):

### Pivot (Excel Formula)

- This is a simplistic approach (all countries need to have 2 consecutive entries with the current and previous date in the same order) based on the video whose link I posted in the comments. An additional task was to flip the date columns.

```
=LET(Table,A1:C7,rCol,1,cCol,2,vCol,3,
    rHead,INDEX(TAKE(Table,1),rCol),
    Data,DROP(Table,1),
    rData,UNIQUE(INDEX(Data,,rCol)),
    cData,TOROW(UNIQUE(INDEX(Data,,cCol))),
    cCols,COLUMNS(cData),
    cSeq,SEQUENCE(,cCols,cCols,-1),
    vData,WRAPROWS(INDEX(Data,,vCol),cCols),
VSTACK(HSTACK(rHead,INDEX(cData,,cSeq)),
    HSTACK(rData,INDEX(vData,SEQUENCE(ROWS(rData)),cSeq))))
```

- If you want it sorted by country like in the other solutions, wrap the last `HSTACK` in a `SORT`.

[image]